# If $B = \varnothing$ then $\bigcup \{A \cup X : X \in B \} = \varnothing$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> If $B = \varnothing$ then $\bigcup \{A \cup X : X \in B \} = \varnothing$ ?

From the definition (as I learn) $ x \in \bigcup \{A \cup X : X \in B \} $ means exists an $X \in B$ such that $x \in A \cup X$,but such $X$ doesn't exist,so every $x$ will fail to be in the set. So $\bigcup \{A \cup X : X \in B \} = \varnothing$.

Am I right?If so, I find it a bit against my intuition.If not,what is it? Hope someone could clear my confusion.

Thanks.

Comment: @drhab could you give more details about how it comes to $\bigcup \{ \varnothing \} $ ?Just because I want to learn how I should deal with such things.

Comment: I have given an answer and hope that things are more clear now.

Comment: I misinformed you in my first comment (sorry) you are not dealing with $\cup\left\{ \emptyset\right\} =\emptyset$ but with $\cup\emptyset=\emptyset$.

Comment: @drhab well you just clear my mind.Thanks.:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ be a set.

Then $\bigcup S$ is a set and is characterized
by $$x\in\bigcup S\iff x\in y\text{ for some }y\in S$$ In fact we
could say that that: $$\bigcup S=\bigcup_{y\in S}y$$

Applying this on set $S=\emptyset$ we come to: $$x\in\bigcup\emptyset\iff x\in y\text{ for some }y\in\emptyset$$
leading to the conclusion that $\bigcup\emptyset$ cannot contain
any elements: $$\bigcup\emptyset=\emptyset$$

Applying this on set $S=\left\{ \emptyset\right\} $ we come to $$x\in\bigcup\left\{ \emptyset\right\} \iff x\in y\text{ for some }y\in\left\{ \emptyset\right\} \iff x\in\emptyset$$
This shows directly that $\bigcup\left\{ \emptyset\right\} =\emptyset$.

Note that $B=\emptyset\Rightarrow S:=\left\{ A\cup X\mid X\in B\right\} =\emptyset$ hence $\bigcup S=\bigcup\emptyset=\emptyset$

---

Also note that: $$A\cup B=\bigcup\left\{ A,B\right\} $$ and: $$\bigcup_{i\in I}A_{i}=\bigcup\left\{ A_{i}\mid i\in I\right\} $$